# How to create paragraphs item programmatically?

Tags: 7, entities

How to create **[paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)** item programmatically?

In Drupal 7 I am using the following code.

```
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $paragraph = new ParagraphsItemEntity(array('field_name' => 'field_name', 'bundle' => 'para_bundlename'));
    $paragraph->is_new = TRUE;
    $paragraph->field_ptest1['und'][0]['value'] = 'Foo';
    $paragraph->setHostEntity('node', $node);
    $paragraph->save();
    node_save($node);
```

But its not working ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code used in various places to create an entity in Drupal 7

```
$node = node_load(...);

$paragraph = new ParagraphsItemEntity(array('field_name' => 'name_of_field_in_node', 'bundle' => 'name_of_paragraph_bundle'));
$paragraph->is_new = TRUE;
$paragraph->setHostEntity('node', $node);
$paragraph->save();
```

Field collection module using the following method instead

```
$node = node_load(...);
$entity = entity_create('paragraphs_item', array('field_name' => 'name_of_field_in_node', 'bundle' => 'name_of_paragraph_bundle'));
$entity->setHostEntity('node', $node);
$entity->save();
```

Both should work fine. You code looks good to me just remove the last line.

Comment: I already tried with both scenario but its not working :(